# JQuery/Javascript - Multiple Variable Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

So my SQL objects currently have "**Name**", "**Desc**".
My current live code on HTML pages looks only at the "**Name**" in SQL for reference to what item info it needs:
 `<a data-name="Washer">Washer</a>`

In SQL, if I update "Washer" with a new name("Washer2"), the html tooltip will break (it cannot find "Washer" anymore when it checks the HTML code).
So I will add a third SQL column to each object in my SQL table: "**Name**", "**Desc**", "**beta-name**". So the SQL info for "**beta-name**" I can have "Washer" and under "**Name**" I can have "Washer2".

I then need to modify my tooltip code to take the name from HTML which is currently "Washer" and cross check it with **two** DB columns now instead of one: "Name" and "beta-name". So when it picks up "Washer" from the HTML, it will check the SQL and see that "Washer2" has a "beta-name" of "Washer" and pull the info for it.

This is a new preservation method I'm trying to implement to prevent breaking old tool-tips with name updates.

I basically need to edit the JQuery/JS tooltip file.
 **This file was created by someone else who has left the project and had the code handed over unfortunately.**

I think I narrowed down the lines of code that need to be changed:

```
var name = jQuery(e.currentTarget).data("name"),
host = globalHost + "/pics/",
url = globalHost + '/getitemid.php?name=' + encodeURI(name) + '&callback=?';
```

Would an array possibly work in this case?

```
    var namesarray = {data("name"), data("beta_name")};
    var name = jQuery(e.currentTarget).data(namesarray),
        host = globalHost + "/pics/",
        url = globalHost + '/getitemid.php?name=' + encodeURI(name) + '&callback=?';
```

Comment: So your HTML element will have either a "name" or a "beta_name" data attribute (but not both?)?

Comment: Sorry. I explained it poorly. On the HTML side we have a paragraph that would look like this:  "Hello our item is a <a data-name="Dishwasher">Dishwasher</a>". So the code looks at "Dishwasher" and then checks the SQL db for something with the same name. Now if we update our SQL for that object with a new name (lets say "Dishwasher A"), the tooltip will break for "Dishwasher". So I basically want to have a secondary SQL row for that item called "beta-name" that will let me put the old name in. So then I want the tooltip code to see "Dishwasher" and check the 2 columns in the DB instead of the 1

Comment: Still not clear.  Your element will have _either_ a "name" _or_ a "beta_name", is that correct?  And then you pass that value to `getitemid.php`?  But on the SQL end, you don't know if that value is a "name" or a "beta_name".  Is that right?

Comment: Hey. I overhauled my initial question to try make it more clear. You might have a read through it. Thanks!

Comment: A couple of things `namesarray` is not an array. `.data("name")` is a getter and `.data(namesarray)` would be a setter. Also why not just use a unique `id` to refer to items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred fix for this problem is to add a primary key to your table (if one doesn't already exist), and then reference that id in your element instead of the name field.  Something like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| ID |  Name  |     Desc     |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 | Washer | I'm a washer |
|  2 | Dryer  | I'm a dryer  |
+----+--------+--------------+

<a data-id="1">Washer</a>
```

That way, you can change the Name whenever you want and nothing breaks.

If that isn't an option for some reason, I think you need to change the SQL query (and not add more data-attributes).  I assume you have a query that looks something like this:

```
select Desc
from items
where Name = @name
```

You need to change it to be:

```
select Desc
from items
where Name = @name or beta-name = @name
```

This of course assumes that you don't have one item with a Name of "Washer" and a different item with a beta-name of "Washer" (because then the query would return both rows because it doesn't know which one you mean).

Comment: Perfect! I went the SQL way and it was far easier than I expected. I was looking for a difficult answer to a very easy solution. So I added the extra SQL column "betaname" and changed my SQL code to: SELECT * FROM item_database WHERE name = '$name' OR betaname = '$name' and it's working perfectly with the betaname! As a note, I originally inserted it was "beta-name" as a SQL column and the "-" was causing errors. Something I didn't know could happen. Changing it to "betaname"  fixed it. Embarrassed it ended up being such a simple solution. Thank you!!